# How to calculate average call time in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, time, average, calculated-field

I have a field in my database for total time a specialist spends on a phone, and another for total calls taken. I am trying to calculate the average call duration but Access won't return the number in a hh:mm:ss format without some coding. I am very new to writing things in VBA though. I tried changing the format on the Average Call Duration field to Long Time, but it shows as a time of day, not average time duration, or am I looking at it wrong?

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue, and if so, how did you get around it?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: What are the data types of your `total time` and `total calls` columns? Can you provide a few example records and the expected output? It'd also be good to see what you are doing right now to get your answer (if it is near working at all)

Comment: the total time is the total amount of time someone spends on the phone for a given month, and the total calls that each person took during the month. They are graded on average call duration both monthly, and for the year

I think part of the problem I am having is that I can't enter 17:42:27 as the total time per month without Access thinking I am entering 5:42 PM

Answer (score 0):

If the time is recorded using data type Date, you can use a query:

```
Select CDate(Avg([TimeSpent])) As TotalTimeSpent
From YourTable
```

You may have to specify the format of the field to: `h:nn`

If your hours will exceed 24, you will have to use a function to create a hh:nn reading:

```
Public Function FormatHourMinute( _
  ByVal datTime As Date, _
  Optional ByVal strSeparator As String = ":") _
  As String

' Returns count of days, hours and minutes of datTime
' converted to hours and minutes as a formatted string
' with an optional choice of time separator.
'
' Example:
'   datTime: #10:03# + #20:01#
'   returns: 30:04
'
' 2005-02-05. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim strHour       As String
  Dim strMinute     As String
  Dim strHourMinute As String

  strHour = CStr(Fix(datTime) * 24 + Hour(datTime))
  ' Add leading zero to minute count when needed.
  strMinute = Right("0" & CStr(Minute(datTime)), 2)
  strHourMinute = strHour & strSeparator & strMinute

  FormatHourMinute = strHourMinute

End Function
```

and then adjust the query:

```
Select FormatHourMinute(CDate(Avg([TimeSpent]))) As TotalTimeSpent
From YourTable
```

Comment: If I convert the time to a string, I won't be able to use that in a calculation though, correct?

Comment: Yes, date/time as string is for display only and should be avoided for storage.

Answer (score 0):

A time field in access is intended to store points of time - not durations. Although you may have chosen "Long Time" as displayformat, access still stores this as a specific date. You can try this out when you format a datetime field as longtime, enter some data into it and then change the format to `tt.mm.jjjj hh:nn:ss` it will give you some time on 30th dec 1899 - the starting date of access-time.

And if you create a query that sums times of the type "long time" and put `tt.mm.jjjj hh:nn:ss` into the format box, it will show you a later date as soon as the sum goes higher than 24 hours.

So to work with durations you normally store everything in the smallest precision you need (hours, minutes, seconds, centuries) in a numbers field and calculate everything from there.
It will be much easier (and safer) to input data in a form than directly into the data-table so you can use time fields that convert the duration automatically.